# pattern matching in pure functions

Tags: lambda, pattern-matching, wolfram-mathematica, anonymous-function, wolfram-language

I need to define a pure function that takes two arguments and returns their quotient. If the divisor is `0` then I want to return `0`.

If I had a named function then I would do

```
div[_, 0]   := 0
div[x_, y_] := x / y
```

how to do the same sort of pattern matching on arguments in a pure function `#1 / #2 &`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Switch` may be useful, for example:

```
Switch[ # ,
       _String , StringLength[#] ,
       _List , Length[#] , 
       __ , Null ] & /@ { "abc", {1, 2, 3, 4}, Pi}
```

> {3, 4, Null}

Answer (score 5):

Try something like

```
If[#2 == 0, 0, #1/#2] &
```

for your pure function.

Comment: thanks. looks like I cannot do pattern matching in a pure function, right? My example is contrived. Yes, I can check if the second argument is zero. I was looking for a way to do pattern matching in general.

Comment: `If[MatchQ[ #, pattern ], ... ] & ` ... or you might want to look at `Switch`

Comment: @agentp thanks, I used `Switch`, please post this comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

One can use a combination of [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) and [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) to achieve a similar pattern matching on the arguments of a pure function

```
Replace[_, {_ /; #2 == 0 -> 0, _ :> #1/#2}] &
```

For example

```
Replace[_, {_ /; #2 == 0 -> 0, _ :> #1/#2}] &[a, 2]
```

> `a/2`

and

```
Replace[_, {_ /; #2 == 0 -> 0, _ :> #1/#2}] &[a, 0]
```

> `0`

---

More approaches and a more extended discussion can be found at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/using-patterns-in-pure-functions